# C++ Using a class from a header within a class

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm having a bit of trouble with classes used within classes, from header files.

I have a class time in time.h:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time  
{
private:
    int hour, minute, second;
public:
    Time();
    ~Time();

    Time(int h, int m, int s);

    int getHour();
    int getMinute();
    int getSecond();

    void setHour(int hour);
    void setMinute(int minute);
    void setSecond(int second);

    Time getTimeFromUser(Time b);
    bool validTime(Time a);
    void print24Hour(Time a);
    void print12Hour(Time b);
};

#endif
```

Schedule.h

```
#ifndef SCHEDULE_H
#define SCHEDULE_H
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;

class Class 
{
    private:
        string name;
        int credits;
        bool majorRequirement;
        double avgGrade;
        string days;

        Time startTime;
        Time endTime;

    public:
        Class();
        ~Class();

        Class(string namae, int cred, bool majorReq, double avg, string day);

        //Mutate
        void setName(string h);
        void setCredits(int c);
        void setMajorRequirement(bool set);
        void setAvgGrade(double g);
        void setDays(string d);

        void getStartTimeFromUser(Time b);
        void getEndTimeFromUser(Time e);

        // Access
        string getName();
        int getCredits();
        bool getMajorRequirement();
        double getAvgGrade();
        string getDays();

        Time& getStartTime();
        Time& getEndTime();
};

#endif
```

Schedule.cpp:

```
Class::Class() 
{
    string name = "";
    int credits = 0;
    bool majorRequirement = false;
    double avgGrade = 0.0;
    string days = "";
}

Time::Time()
{
    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
}

Class::Class(string namae, int cred, bool majorReq, double avg, string day) 
{
    name = namae;
    credits = cred;
    majorRequirement = majorReq;
    avgGrade = avg;
    days = day;
}

Time::Time(int h, int m, int s)
{
    second = s;
    minute = m;
    hour = h;
}

Time getTimeFromUser(Time b)
{
    string time = "";

    string hourS, minuteS, secondS = new string();

    getline(cin,time);

    hourS = time.substr(0,2);
    minuteS = time.substr(3,2);
    secondS = time.substr(6,2);

    b.hour = atoi(hourS.c_str());
    b.minute = atoi(minuteS.c_str());
    b.second = atoi(secondS.c_str());

    return b;
}

void getStartTimeFromUser(Time b)
{
    startTime = getTimeFromUser(b);
}

void getEndTimeFromUser(Time e)
{
    endTime = getTimeFromUser(e);
}


Other Mutators and Accessors here.
```

Main is long. Here is the severely condensed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include "time.h"
#include "schedule.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Expecting that variables are properly declared

    Class * klass = new Class[classcount];

    cout << "Enter the start time for the class (format is HH:MM:SS): ";
    klass[i].getStartTimeFromUser(classB);

    cout << "Enter the end time for the class (format is HH:MM:SS): ";
    klass[i].getEndTimeFromUser(classE);

for(int i = 0; i < classcount; i++)
    {
    // Data collected via getline and changed through mutators/accessors
    // Problems arise when working with Time

    klass[i].getStartTime().print24hour();
    }
}
```

I get quite a few "hour, second, minute, etc." are private errors, I'm guessing I'm doing something simple in a rather wrong way. Please help.

I get a lot of this:

```
time.h:10:7: error: ‘int Time::hour’ is private
schedule.cpp:146:4: error: within this context
time.h:10:13: error: ‘int Time::minute’ is private
schedule.cpp:147:4: error: within this context
time.h:10:21: error: ‘int Time::second’ is private
schedule.cpp:148:4: error: within this context
schedule.cpp: In function ‘void getStartTimeFromUser(Time)’:
schedule.cpp:155:16: error: ‘setStartTime’ was not declared in this scope
schedule.cpp: In function ‘void getEndTimeFromUser(Time)’:
schedule.cpp:160:2: error: ‘endTime’ was not declared in this scope
time.h: In function ‘bool validTime(Time)’:
```

Comment: are you sure this is your actual code? There is a lot of invalid code, missing include guards, etc.

Comment: @phresnel: I doubt that the compiler likes the dots and the etc's 8^)

Comment: No, I rewrote this as simply as possible for the sake of brevity, it's more of an outline.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to give you a good answer, e.g. where is `getStartTime`?

Comment: @Zane: I named the etc's already!!! pff

Comment: @Kotsuzui: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the error message you get.

Comment: I tried to answer everyone's demands, expanded it quite a bit. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kotsuzui: (this is still not a complete example, e.g. there are include-directives missing) As an important sidenote: Considering how you are wrongly using dynamic arrays, not using initializer syntax, using `using namespace` in a header, and more, please, for your own sake, get a good introductory book on C++ before getting into class design. Also: A short include guard with a general name like `TIME_H` is prone to name clashes. Maybe not now, but later.

Comment: Isn't berating someone for lack of knowledge when they're asking for help a bit... unhelpful? I'm learning how to use C++ classes, forgive me for not knowing everything about them.

Comment: @phresnel: I didn't want to be rude. But from the dots and etc's it was already clear that part of the code was intentionally(?) left out.

Comment: @Kotsuzui: I am not berating, at least that's not my intention. I was really trying to give the advice of going step-by-step. C++ can be used extremely wrong and dangerous, and the best start are good learning resources. Don't take it as berating, but advice.

Comment: @Zane: Of I was trying to be funny there. Sorry if I sounded rude; I seem to fail at being funny.

Comment: @phresnel: Yep seems we both forget the irony tasks 8^)

Answer (score 3):

There are several errors in your code:

- I assume `class` in your `main()` function represents an array of
  `Class`; but this is illegal, since `class` is a C++ keyword.
- You are trying to access a private member of a `Class` object
  (`class[i].startTime`). This is illegal again. You would need a
  public accessor to that data member:
- You are calling a function that does not exist (`print24()`). If you
  intended to call `print24hour()`, this function takes no parameters.

Putting it all together, you need to do three things:

1. Add an accessor for `startTime` in `Class`:

   ```
   class Class
   {
     //...
   public:
     Time GetStartTime() {return startTime;}
   };
   ```
2. Use a legal name for your array and use `std::vector` or `std::array`:

   ```
   std::vector<Class> classArray;
   // OR:
   std::array<Class, SIZE> classArray;
   ```
3. Call the right methods correctly:

   ```
   classArray[i].GetStartTime().print24hour();
   ```

Comment: `GetStartTime()` would usually return a `const` ref, but `print24hour()` is not const and I assume you have no control on that, so you cannot do that.

Comment: `Class classArray[];` is illegal.

Comment: @jrok I don't know how is that array being filled; I just wanted to make it clear that the name must change. I'm adding a comment to clarify that.

Comment: I was referrign to missing size specifier. OP is completely confused as it is, don't confuse him even more :)

Comment: @jrok You are right. Anyway, since Griwes decided to change that on his own, this is no longer relevant.

Comment: #1 & #2 were because I oversimplified for the sake of brevity, sorry for the errors. #3 helps, thanks. Now for the other errors ;(

Comment: @Kotsuzui: The other errors are very similar. You are using private data members instead of the appropriate public methods. E.g.: instead of `b.hour = atoi(hourS.c_str())`, you should use `b.setHour( atoi(hourS.c_str()))`.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to access `class[i].startTime.print24(getStartTime())` from `main` you need to make `startTime`public.

If this is good style is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the private members of a class using the object directly.

Please read about public and private access specifiers [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/83-public-vs-private-access-specifiers/).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Class
{
    private:
      Time startTime;

    public:
      const Time & getStartTime(){
        return startTime;
      }    
};

int main()
{
    Class c;
    c.getStartTime().print24Hour(); 
}
```

You want either that, or make `startTime` public.

Note the `const`; if you don't want the returned reference to be `const`, then make `startTime` public right now. You may think that making it `private` improves encapsulation; and yes, it does, as long as you don't provide read-write access to the variable, which happens if you don't mark the member function return type `const`.

If your printing function isn't marked `const`, then your const-correctness doesn't exist. If using const reference as return type here, then you have some things to fix.

Related reading: [Pseudo-Classes and Quasi-Classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Comment: Your `getStartTime` is wrong. You don't want to return the address of `startTime`, but just the value.

Comment: @honk, right. It was shameless copy-paste with changing reference type alone :P